# Having issues moving file and folder from one directory to another

Tags: command-line, bash, mv

I have used this code but this is the error message:

```
xxxxxxx~$ mv  -v ~/var/www/html/* ~/var/www/
error message - mv: cannot stat '/home/tall/var/www/html/*
```

But I was able to open the directory using:

```
cd
xxxxxxxx:/var/www/html$ ls -al
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

/var is not in your home folder. The command you want is:

```
sudo mv -v /var/www/html/* /var/www/
```

Answer (score 0):

To explain more about your error, the `~` in bash expands to `/home/$USER` which is your home directory. So `~/var/www` was never created by you so doesn't exists. That (`~/var/www`) if expanded would be `/home/your_username/var/www`. So leaving out the `~` as  done by ravery would be the right command.